# minimize execution time by applying java multithreading

Tags: java, multithreading

I have a list of persons 
e.g.: List persons= new ArrayList(); //contains 1000000 items

I petitioned it as
List persons persons1=persons.subList(0, 500000);
List persons persons2=persons.subList(500000, 9999999);

now, i wanted to print these two lists in parallel applying threading. My purpose is to minimize the execution time.

When I print list of persons it takes 8-10 secs.
But, when I apply threading to print persons1 and persons2 in parallel it takes same time.
Two threads are running in parallel to print  persons1  and persons2 means that the tasks are equally divided. So, the the time should be less.

But, I don't get they are taking the same time.

Please help me out to find how i can minimize the execution time applying multi-threading.

Comment: Let's say 1000 cars have to cross a bridge which has only one lane. Will it be faster if the road coming to that bridge has 1 or 2 lanes? Same here: there is only one output stream, and 2 threads are writing to it, so they have to coordinate. All the hard work (printing) can only be done by one thread at a time. Side note: you forgot the last person in your list.

Comment: And since the output stream will act like a lock, adding threads to it will probably make the print slower

Comment: What system are you running on? E.g. depending on how much memory you have there may be better ways than multi-threading for increasing efficiency (e.g. not keeping ten million objects in memory at the same time).

Comment: I am using a machine with following configuration: Processor: Intel Duo Centrino 1.73 GHZ + 1.73 GHZ         RAM: 3GB

Comment: Hi, JB Nizet I got your point regarding the problem of printing. I am not being able to make the execution time faster even if I implement Callable and return some thing in parallel rather then printing.